# laravel PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel

Hello I am trying to deploy my laravel application in google engine. I am following this [tutorial](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/)
step by step. But at step 7 it displays the following error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>
> PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open C:\Windows.apc.a04316

Does anyone know why is this error?

Comment: because you cannot create filesystem level locks in app engine. not sure why it wants to do that.

Comment: how to do it? how to put my laravel application in app engine?

Comment: the blog post works for me - perhaps try it again and make sure you're following the instructions properly.

Comment: now it shows this error :Class 'Logger' not found  I am using laravel 4.1. May be the problem?

Comment: or may the problem be with python or sdk? i dont know , i have installed them already. I am confused after trying even this http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/ and shows me Class Logger not found

Comment: sorry I am writing so much comments. I started again the firs tutorial and now i have a syntax error at require_once 'google/appengine/api/app_identity/AppIdentityService.php'
use \google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService;

// Define the gethostname function if it does not exist
if (!function_exists('gethostname')) {
    function gethostname() {
        return AppIdentityService::getApplicationId();
    }
}   at second line. Did you had the same ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google App Engine Launcher be sure open it using "Run as administrator" before you run your app.